# alias analysis and _restrict keyword - C

Tags: c, llvm, alias, static-analysis, restrict

How alias analysis works with keywords like `__restrict` and `__noalias` ?
Does it regard them as proof of no aliasing? 
Or simply calculates its own results depending on the pointers?

Looking at the results of alias analysis of LLVM, in many tight loops doing loads-binop-store sequences, the following bottleneck was seen: 
Even though the input and output pointers were marked amply with `__restrict`, the alias analysis still assumed them as '`MayAlias`' and made the stores at the end of the loop dependent on ALL the loads in the loop.

e.g.

```
void _BitwiseOr_(unsigned char * __restrict * __restrict src1Addr, unsigned char * __restrict * __restrict src2Addr, unsigned char * __restrict * __restrict destAddr, unsigned int width) {
        uchar16 * __restrict src1 = (uchar16 * __restrict) *src1Addr;
      uchar16 * __restrict src2 = (uchar16 * __restrict) *src2Addr;
      uchar16 * __restrict dest = (uchar16 * __restrict) *destAddr;


        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width; i += 4) {
        *dest++ = *src1++ | *src2++;
        *dest++ = *src1++ | *src2++;
        *dest++ = *src1++ | *src2++;
        *dest++ = *src1++ | *src2++;
        }
    }
```

.

```
define void @_BitwiseOr_(i8** noalias nocapture readonly %src1Addr, i8** noalias nocapture readonly %src2Addr, i8** noalias nocapture readonly %destAddr, i32 %width) local_unnamed_addr #0 {
entry:
  %0 = bitcast i8** %src1Addr to <16 x i8>**
  %1 = load <16 x i8>*, <16 x i8>** %0, align 4, !tbaa !2  
  %2 = bitcast i8** %src2Addr to <16 x i8>**
  %3 = load <16 x i8>*, <16 x i8>** %2, align 4, !tbaa !2    
  %4 = bitcast i8** %destAddr to <16 x i8>**
  %5 = load <16 x i8>*, <16 x i8>** %4, align 4, !tbaa !2         
  %6 = load <16 x i8>, <16 x i8>* %1, align 8, !tbaa !6
  %7 = load <16 x i8>, <16 x i8>* %3, align 8, !tbaa !6
  %or = or <16 x i8> %7, %6
  store <16 x i8> %or, <16 x i8>* %5, align 8, !tbaa !6
  ret void
}
```

Alias analysis answers that the only NO ALIASES are between:

```
i8** src1addr - i8** src2addr,
i8** src1addr - i8** destaddr,
i8** src2addr - i8** destaddr,
i8** destaddr - i8** destaddr,
i8** src1addr - i8** src1addr,
i8** src2addr - i8** src2addr
```

Why does it not 'benefit' of the use of `__restrict` keyword?
Is it possible to make it work?

Above is compiled by clang with:

```
-cc1 -S -disable-free -main-file-name file.cpp -mllvm -disable-block-placement -funroll-loops -mllvm -unroll-allow-partial -mllvm -tail-merge-size=71 -mllvm -tail-dup-size=70 -fmath-errno -v -gcodeview -dwarf-column-info -coverage-file file.s -O3 -Wall -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -std=c++14 -fdeprecated-macro -fno-dwarf-directory-asm -ferror-limit 19 -fmessage-length 0 -ffreestanding -fallow-half-arguments-and-returns -fobjc-runtime=gcc -fdiagnostics-show-option -vectorize-loops -vectorize-slp -mllvm -no-phi-elim-live-out-early-exit -mllvm -use-cfl-aa=anders -mllvm -use-cfl-aa-in-codegen=anders -mllvm -debug -mllvm -da-delinearize -mllvm -mllvm -enable-tbaa -mllvm -enable-scoped-noalias -mllvm -evaluate-aa-metadata -mllvm -print-all-alias-modref-info
```

Comment: What other "no aliases" are you expecting? The list you provided seems to cover all the inputs?

Comment: I should expect also the %1 - %3,  %3 - %5 aka the src1 - src2  etc  (Check updated source code )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the rules in the C Standard.

"restrict" pointers can of course alias. It's just that this generates in some cases undefined behaviour, so they alias, but the compiler is completely allowed to ignore this.

You also need to be aware that "restrict" only affects pointers that are derived from a "restrict" pointer vs. pointers that are guaranteed not derived from the same "restrict" pointer. For example, if p is a "restrict" pointer and you call f (p), that call could store p into any static or global pointer variable. So if you read such a pointer variable after the call, the compiler doesn't know whether it's derived from the restrict pointer or not, and if it is derived from p then alias rules apply.

Comment: But according to the C standard: It does not specify directly when aliasing is and is not possible. However, it states
that an object of one type shall have its stored value accessed only by a reference that has one
of a handful of related types.Implicitly, then, pairs of accesses with types inconsistent with
that list cannot alias. Restating these rules in terms of aliasing, the types that are compatible when qualifiers (const, volatile, and restrict) are
ignored! That's why my query here remains...

Comment: The rules clang and gcc use for deciding when a pointer is "based upon" a restrict-qualified pointer neither match intuition (which would suggest that any pointer of the form `(ptr+intvalue)` would be based upon `ptr`) nor the corner-cases mandated by the Standard.